# (UWP) C# Get Node on RightTapped Treeview

Tags: c#, uwp, treeview

So I am trying to get the specific `TreeViewNode` when right clicked using the `RightTapped` event handler, however `RightTappedRoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource` returns the `Treeview` itself, not the node I right clicked. Same issue with the sender object.

I have also tried selecting the node first and checking the treeview's selectednodes but that is empty and anyways, ideally I don't want to have to select the node first.

NodeMouseClick doesn't exist in UWP.Any help would be amazing, project is a C# UWP app.

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-determine-which-treeview-node-was-clicked-windows-forms

Comment: I don't have AfterSelect or GetNodeAt for mouse events.

Comment: All the method contains is to get the text name of node to determine which Node was clicked.  All I usually do is to make each node of the treeview a control like a button or a textbox.  Then register the control as its own event.  MSDN webpages are not very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UWP [TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.treeview), there is an [ItemInvoked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.treeview.iteminvoked) event which occurs when an item in the tree is invoked. You can use this event to get the clicked Node.

```
private void MyTreeView_ItemInvoked(TreeView sender, TreeViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(((TreeViewNode)args.InvokedItem).Content);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just have to note that  `TreeViewNode` cold be your custom class. Pls see `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/tree-view#tree-view-using-data-binding`